# Get success confirmation before moving ahead

Tags: php

In my page, I'm passing a user's value to a url and getting serialized values returned.

```
$test = unserialize ( file_get_contents ( "http://www.website.com/?info=$inf" ) );
$date = $test["dob"];
$id = $test["id"];
if($date != ""){
    //do something
} else{
    //do something else
}

//continue with the rest
```

How can I be sure that the `$test` values are returned before moving to the if statement line?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

There are no asynchronous requests done so the if statement will be always reached after getting the content

Comment: Is this actually what OP asked?

Comment: yes.. he wants to be sure that those test variables will contain something before reaching the if statement..

Comment: @jurgemaister I think that this answer is indeed what OP asked

Comment: The fact that it's a synchronous request doesn't guarantee that the `$test` var will have contents, though.

Comment: That's true.. but the if statement will be reached even if there is nothing returned in the request.. the op must do the necessary validation before doing any other step